# Rich Text content control data binding with docx4j

Tags: docx4j

Trying to create a data binding to custom XML part for a sdtBlock representing a rich text content control is not working because it creates a w:dataBinding tag in the resulting XML instead of a w15:dataBinding. Rich text content control require a w15 namespace uri.

I am creating the data binding directly in Java, not in an authoring tool, with this code:

```
org.docx4j.wml.CTDataBinding cTDataBinding = new CTDataBinding();
```

And there is no data binding class in org.docx4j.w15 package.

Is there any way to specify that a different namespace should be used for this instance when marshalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-openxml-objects/src/main/java/org/docx4j/w15/ObjectFactory.java#L232 contains:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml", name = "dataBinding")
public JAXBElement<CTDataBinding> createDataBinding(CTDataBinding value) {
    return new JAXBElement<CTDataBinding>(_DataBinding_QNAME, CTDataBinding.class, null, value);
}
```

so you should be able to create what you want using the w15 ObjectFactory.  For example:

```
    SdtPr sdtPr = new SdtPr();      
    JAXBElement<CTDataBinding> w15DataBinding = new org.docx4j.w15.ObjectFactory().createDataBinding(new CTDataBinding());      
    sdtPr.getRPrOrAliasOrLock().add(w15DataBinding);        
    System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(sdtPr));
```

produces (omitting some namespaces):

```
<w:sdtPr xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" >
    <w15:dataBinding/>
</w:sdtPr>
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your answer. I have tested this using this code:

JAXBElement<CTDataBinding> w15DataBinding = new org.docx4j.w15.ObjectFactory().createDataBinding(new CTDataBinding());
sdtElement.getSdtPr().setDataBinding(w15DataBinding.getValue());

But the ouptut docx is still setting the databinding as w namespace prefix, instead of w15, so Word opens that content control as Plain Text, instead of Rich Text

Comment: Thank you so much @JasonPlutext. Adding the databinding that way works perfectly!